# How to call function once with scroll function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll, jquery-events

I have `.viewPort` Area that contain large element with scroll.

And create function some thing like flowing code:

**jQuery:**

```
$('.part').each(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':in-viewport') ){
        var partID = $(this).attr('id');
        if($('.part #content-id-'+(partID)+').length < 1) {
            partLoader(partID);
        }                       
    }
});

function partLoader(id) {
    // do some ajax actions
    //$.ajax({....});
    console.log('done');
}
```

when I scroll I get a lot of `done` in console.log and the browser crashed!!!

I know that is for sending too much `partLoader()` to server because of scroll event!

so... how can I call `partLoader` once with scroll?

Comment: you're calling the function for every `.part`, I think what's happening is many `.part` elements are all meeting the conditions. Is there a way you can restrict which ones send the AJAX call?

Comment: how can I restrict the AJAX...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. consider not doing `$('.part').each()` but instead `$('.part').last()` (whether that works or not will depend on the structure of your site, so I can't be sure.)
2. use `.part` more sparingly, so it generates less requests.
3. use better if statements to filter out more `.part` elements that don't need the update.
4. use a [debouncer](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)...

i don't think 4 would be necessary since it looks like a structural problem with how you are calling the AJAX (from every `.part` element instead of ones that need it- but I can't offer much more advice without knowing more about the structure), but it's something that will limit the # of AJAX calls.